# Cauchy residue formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate the integral of $1/z$ around $C$, where $C$ is any contour going from $-\sqrt{3}+i$ to $-\sqrt{3}-i$ and is contained in the set of complex numbers whose real part is negative.

My answer: Let $f=1/z$ Then $f$ has a simple pole at $z=0$ with residue 1. But 0 is not enclosed in the contour, so in fact the integral is zero. Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. Why don't you simply choose a contour and compute it? You will see it is nonzero..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a closed curve.  Calculate the logarithm at both points, but remember the angle $\theta$ remains between $-\pi$ and $0$ for the whole path.

Comment: Doing the integral I get $ln(-\sqrt{3}-i)-ln(-\sqrt{3}+i)$. Is that right and can this be simplified further by using log laws?

Comment: Convert to polar coordinates $re^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 2):

What you did isn't correct. You seem to be using the residue theorem which requires the path to be closed, but since the endpoints are different, there is no such path. 
Even if such path existed somehow, you'd still need to justify that $0$ lies outside the region enclosed by the path, but of course such a region isn't well defined.

To find the integral note that $z\mapsto \dfrac 1 z$ has an antiderivative in the set of complex numbers with negative real part and use this chain of equalities (which justifies that the value of the integral is path indepedent):
$$\int _\gamma f=\int \limits _a^b f\left(\gamma (t)\right)\gamma '(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int \limits_a^b (F\circ \gamma)'(t)\,\mathrm dt=F\left(\gamma (b)\right)-F(\gamma(a)),$$

where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

Comment: Thanks. What can an I use for gamma?

Comment: @user137090 why not a straight line between your two endpoints?

Comment: @user137090 You don't even need a path, you just need an antiderivative.